# How to write stylish letter and text with in the specific fashion?

Tags: fonts, symbols

How to write four big size letters in a single line with some text.

See below:

[image]

My LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{real try}

\date{November 2017}

\begin{document}

$$Used data structures = S \hspace{4} S^{'} \hspace{4} T$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. It is very hard to tell from your question precisely what you want. What do you mean by "four big size letters"? Your handwritten example only has three. Post your MWE and then say exactly what changes you'd like to make.

Comment: You should use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`. Also, in math mode, `S'` is probably what you want instead of `S^{'}`. To have your text appear as text but maintain proper math spacing for the `=` sign, enclose it in an `\mbox`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind?

[image]

The code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{rc@{}c@{}c@{}c}
\mbox{Used data structures}&=&\underbrace{S}&\underbrace{S'}&\underbrace{T}\\
&&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow\\
&&\begin{tabular}{c}\scriptsize{Explicit}\\[-.75ex] \scriptsize{Stack}\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{c}\scriptsize{Implicit}\\[-.75ex] \scriptsize{Stack}\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{c}\scriptsize{Trailer}\\[-.75ex] \scriptsize{Stack}\end{tabular}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am trying to add pause also to make visually more elegant. I mean one pause before S and one pause before S' etc. Do you have any idea how to do it and also to pause in arrows

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by pause.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add _space_ before the `S` and between `S` and `S'`? If so, you can add `\hspace{5mm}` inside the `{}` in the `\begin{array}` command. There are three `{}` pairs. You can add as much space as you wish for each by replacing `5mm` with any length.

Comment: No I mean pause which work when use itemize.

Comment: There may be a language/translation issue here. I think pause may be the wrong word. Can you describe more specifically what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\Stack#1#2{\underbrace{#1}_{\underset{%
\begin{subarray}{c}
\text{\vphantom{p}#2}\\\text{Stack}
\end{subarray}}
{\downarrow}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\text{Used data structures}=\Stack{S}{Explicit}\ \Stack{S'}{Implicit}\ \Stack{T}{Trailer}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am trying to add pause also to make visually more elegant. I mean one pause before S and one pause before S' etc. Do you have any idea how to do it and also to pause in arrows